# Clearing router fragment in Angular 6

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an angular app, using Angular 6 and NgRX 6.

I have an identity server I am talking to via the implicit flow, that once redirects back to my app, has my token response and so on still in the navigation bar.

I would like to clear that fragment from the url and remain on my route.

For example

```
http://foo.com/bar/boo#key=value
```

I would like to clear this once I am finished and be left on

```
http://foo.com/bar/boo
```

I am handling this in an effect, as follows

```
 @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  persistSessionTokens$: Observable<void> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<ActionWithPayload>(SET_SESSION_TOKENS),
    map(action => action.payload),
    tap(tokens => {
      persist(ID_TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY, tokens[ID_TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY]);
      persist(ACCESS_TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY, tokens[ACCESS_TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY]);

      const url = this.router.url;

      this.router.navigate([url], { replaceUrl: true });
    }),
    catchError(error => of({ type: SET_TOKEN_FAILURE, payload: error }))
  );
```

However this redirects me to
`http://foo.com/bar/`

My application in this case has a base href of `bar`

`boo` is the name of my tenant, so it is important I retain this structure in the url.

Comment: Did you try `window.location.hash =  ''` ?

Comment: This works from the console, however when fired from within my effect it does not seem to work. I was hoping to avoid touching the window object directly and keeping any state changes within Angular / NgRX - unless this is acceptable in this case?

Comment: Well fragments aren't that useful angularly speaking, it's more of a user convenience. I don't tell you it's a bad practice, I just know this way. And remove your effect to use that, you don't need it anymore

Comment: This worked like a charm user4676340

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Location` class from `@angular/common`. Here is the example:

```
// This will give you current location path without including hash
// path(includeHash: boolean = false): string
const pathWithoutHash = this.location.path(false); 

// This changes the browsers URL to the normalized 
// version of the given URL, and replaces the 
// top item on the platform's history stack.
// replaceState(path: string, query: string = '', state: any = null): void
this.location.replaceState(pathWithoutHash);
```

[For more about `Location`](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#subclasses)

Comment: That's a lot cleaner than what I was doing. I was checking if the `this.router.url` included a hash, then using split, and grabbing the first item of the array and doing `this.location.replaceState()` with that — probably what it's doing internally, but I like using API provided tools for frameworks; feels better. Thank you!!